# Excel VBA To Filecopy from Sharepoint to Network Folder No Longer Working

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel VBA Code, I had a simple command to copy a file from my internal Sharepoint Site to a local network drive.

```vb
source_file = "//intranet.gbop.org/CR/PublicFiles/3218.pdf"
dest-File = "I:\AFB Info\3218.pdf"
FileCopy source_file dest_file
```

Last Week the above worked fine.  After I updated my Windows Password, the above now fails with a
Run-time error "75"
Path/File access error

I have a ticket into my help desk but can anyone opine whether it was because of the password reset?

Comment: Try connecting to your sharepoint site *using IE* and your new credentials.  I seem to recall something about needing to do that periodically in order to keep the authentication in order.

Comment: Likely relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives

Comment: It was indeed that someone my connection to Sharepoint was using my old password.  Once I forced the connection to start using my new password.  Worked just like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely because of the password reset, VBA may be using your old credentials, as  you have manually entered them into the VBA.

Just scan through the connection code and see if that has a copy pasted version of your Credentials *(Also don't do that, unsecure AF if any one gets a copy of your Excel, they have a backdoor to your Sharepoint in your VBA)*...

[This may help if that is the case](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272896/vba-autheticate-to-sharepoint-office-365)

If you are however using the linked version and are still getting the error then Helpdesk will need to update your Sharepoint to match your Microsoft login, which is odd because that should be happening by default which is why I think you maybe stored them in the VBA.

Comment: It turns out the Sharepoint "connection" was using my old password.  Once I forced it to the new password, worked as expected.